# Symmetry breaking of eigenvalues of parameter-dependent periodic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, complex-analysis

In my research I deal with parameter dependent periodic matrices $M(\chi)=M(\chi+p)$, which have to be non-Hermitian and $det[\, M(\chi=0)\,]=0 \,$. When I calculate the eigenvalues of such a matrix, I encounter situations (meaning different values of other parameters apart from $\chi$ defining $M$, for which $M$ is in general non-periodic), where the set of eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_k \}$ shows non-analytic behaviour at some special points of the parameter $\chi_p \,$. This can be reformulated, if I continue the eigenvalues analytically, in terms of a broken periodicity. Some eigenvalues as a function of $\chi$ may show a broken periodicity.

$$ \lambda_i(\chi+\nu  p)=\lambda_i(\chi) \, \text{with} \, \nu \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

And as a consequence of the overall periodicity of $M(\chi)\,$:

$$ \lambda_i(\chi+p)=\lambda_j(\chi) \, \text{for} \, i \neq j$$

An easy example would be:
$$M(\chi)=\begin{pmatrix}
-2a & (1-a) \\
2a & -(1-a)
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
-2b & (1-b)e^{i\chi} \\
2be^{-i\chi} & -(1-b)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\lambda_{0/1}(\chi)=\frac{1}{2} \left(-(2 + a + b)\pm \sqrt{(-2 + a)^2 + 2 (-2 + 9a)b + b^2 + f(\chi)} \, \right)
$$

$$
\text{with }f(\chi)= 8(a + b - 2a b)cos(\chi) + 8 i (a - b)sin(\chi)
$$
The non-analytic behavior of the eigenvalues arises for parameters $a=1 \, b=0$, whereas the spectrum is 'trivial' in that sense for $a=b=0.5$. The two plots each show the two eigenvalues as a function of $ \chi \,$.
[non-analytic behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpSwh.png) and [trivial behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvfeC.png)

My question is: **Are there any mathematical theorems and or tools that are predicting such a behaviour, without the need to calculate the eigenvalues explicitly** ?

Thank you for your time in advance!

The example is heavily inspired by [RR18](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.06468). The matrix can be found on page 7, equations (10) and (11), followed by a discussion of the eigenspectrum on page 8, equations (12) and (13).

Comment: What does "non-analytic behavior" mean?

Comment: It means that the eigenvalues make jumps. In the example I gave, the eigenvalues of the 2x2 matrix have a complex square root, which can cross a branch cut while changing the parameter $a$ ( which you can see in eqs (12) and (13) of the reference I gave). Due to the overall symmetry the corresponding eigenvalues "jump" into one another.

Answer (score 1):

I think in a sense, your question is equivalent to asking when the roots of an $n$'th degree polynomial $p(x)$ are analytic in the coefficients of $p$. There's a reference here which is unfortunately paywalled:

[The Analyticity of the Roots of a Polynomial as Functions of the Coefficients - Brillinger, 1966](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689304?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

The answer is something like this: the roots will be analytic in any region where they retain their multiplicity.

So you necessarily get non-analyticity when roots cross, e.g. change multiplicity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure, whether this is applicable for matrices, whose eigenvalues I cannot calculate analytically, e.g. for matrices of dimension five or bigger.

Comment: @Jakob S: the eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of its characteristic polynomial. There’s no obvious way of foreseeing what this polynomial is unless the family of matrices falls into a specific class.